# Which Boost Libraries take advantage of Move Semantics

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, rvalue-reference, move-semantics

Rvalue references and Move semantics are a major C++11 feature that can significantly speed up code by reducing unnecessary copies. The STL has been updated to use this new feature when a c++11/0x compiler is used (e.g. gcc 4.6)

Boost 1.48 introduced a new library in order to emulate move semantics on older C++03 compilers. This library works by introducing macros that expand to true rvalue references when code is compiled with C++11 compilers or emulated rvalue referneces when the code is compiled with C++03 compilers.

Apart from `boost::container` have any of the other boost libraries been updated to take advantage of move semantics yet?

Is there a roadmap detailing when / if move semantics will be added to other boost libraries?

`boost::multi_index_container` has mentioned addition of move semantics on the 
[Boost.MultiIndex Future work](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/multi_index/doc/future_work.html#move_semantics), since it was introduced in version 1.31.

Comment: Note: name "STL" is deprecated and ambiguous. Use "C++ standard library" instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you said in the question, boost 1.48 introduced `boost::move`, a library that emulates move semantics with C++03. This was developed by Ion Gaztanaga, who also (mostly) wrote and currently maintains `boost::intrusive` and `boost::container`.

Both intrusive and container support move semantics - in fact `boost::intrusive` has to support move semantics for `boost::container` to, because `boost::container` is basically a bunch of non-intrusive containers implemented by wrapping their `boost::intrusive` counterparts. It looks to me like intrusive/container were the motivation for writing `boost::move`, so it's not surprising that they have a head start on the rest of boost.

But it's import to note here that there is no boost roadmap or committee - boost is just a collection of libraries that share distribution, a website, and a review/quality control process.  You have to consider each library as a separate project, which will only be updated if and when the authors/maintainers are interested in doing the work (or of course, when you send them a patch!).

[The boost 1.48](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_48_0.html)/[1.49](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_49_0.html)/[1.50](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_50_0.html)/[1.51](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_51_0.html)/[1.52 release notes](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_52_0.html) are the best place to look for solid answers:

- **Boost.Interprocess** has support since 1.45, both C++11 and C++03. Before 1.48, this contained the code that became boost.move.
- **Boost.Asio** has support since 1.47; no emulation in C++03
- **Boost.Intrusive** gained support via boost.move in 1.48 (C++11, C++03)
- **Boost.Container** was new in 1.48 with support via boost.move (C++11, C++03)
- **Boost.Icl** gained support via boost.move in 1.49 (C++11, C++03)
- **Boost.Unordered** gained support via boost.move in 1.49 (C++11, with a `#define` to enable emulation in C++03)
- **Boost.Thread** supports C++03 emulation w/boost.move since 1.50, older versions have C++11-only support
- **Boost.Function** added C++11-only support in 1.52